Unity 2D object not coming to the front problem
My confirmation panel, which I added in my Unity 2D game, does not come in front of my title.

The layers look like this, but they still look transparent, they stay behind, but in the same way, they can get in the way of the start button. I could never understand the problem. I've been trying since the morning.
I tried every way but I never succeeded. I wanted my Confirmation panel component to open the confirmation window and come to the front when I pressed the cross button before exiting the game.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

gameobject based UI or the UI toolkit? for gameobject based order in heirachy matters

I couldn't add any photos... Cause I am new..

The order of layering on the canvas is based on hierarchical order.  The higher an object is in the hierarchy, the further back it will be rendered. So, Lower your QuitConfirmationPanel in the hierarchy below the Title object and Play/Start button object.


My hieyarchy is same... But it doesn't work. Why idk...

@SemihApdik I think you didn't quite grasp the point of the red arrow there .. you should move your panel to the bottom - so that it is the last child of your canvas - in order to have it been rendered last (= on top of anything else) .. This is for the new UIToolkit but the same basically applies to Canvas as well
